# How do I deserialize TimeOnly (c#) from json?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am currently doing the following:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

The object `product` has objects of type `TimeOnly`.  The serialize part works but the deserialize causes it to crash. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the error ?

Comment: TimeOnly/DateOnly was added to Newtonsoft.Json in 13.0.2-beta1. Try this version...

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2521

Supported in 13.0.2 betas.  `System.Text.Json` supports it.